# Immigrant visa expiry

Tags: usa

My father's USA immigrant visa date mentioned on his passport got expired and he could not go as my grand mother was sick. Rest of my family migrated and are green card holders now.
My father wants to go too now 
What should he be doing now ? 
Whom should he contact or email .... 
It's been 4 and a half month since his visa got expired.

Answer (score 2):

According to the US Embassy in Moscow,

> 12. What happens if my visa expired and I didn’t use it?
>
> Please contact U.S. Embassy Moscow to find out whether your visa may be re-issued and to receive further instructions. E-mail inquiries may be addressed to consulmo@state.gov.

Source: https://moscow.usembassy.gov/iv-faq.html

Obviously, if your father's immigrant visa was issued by a different mission, your father should get in touch with that mission instead of the Moscow embassy.

Comment: [This article](http://m.jamaicaobserver.com/mobile/news/ask-us-embassy/Ask-the-US-Embassy--Expiration-of-immigrant-visa-documents_10922699), while unofficial, is accurate. The visa expires about 6 months after the interview date. Since he's 10.5 months past that he'll likely need a new medical and police report and to file a new DS-260 (they all expire after a year), pay the fees again and schedule a new interview. That'll likely take another 6 months, minimally.

Comment: @Dennis from where will I get DS 260? And it's 4 and half months since the expiry date.

Comment: I have sent emails to NVC but they did not respond yet. Visa was issued by Islamabad US Embassy.

Comment: Should I be sending DS-260 , medical and police reports on my own to embassy or  I need to contact US embassy first  ? What is the first step I need to take?@ Dennis

Comment: @user51901 get in touch with the embassy first.

Comment: @user51901 The first step is to contact the US embassy or consulate that issued the visa. This is printed at the top center of the visa under "Issuing Post".

Comment: How to get appointment from Embassy for such issue ? Any idea ?

Comment: @user51901 go to the website for that embassy or consulate, and see if you can find a question/answer page addressing the question, similar to the quoted material above from the Moscow embassy. It should have an e-mail address or some other way of getting in touch with them. If not, call the main phone number.